# mvn property is not getting overriden with -D option

Tags: maven, cmake, protoc

In my pom.xml, I have a property for `protocPath`:

```
    <properties>
        <protobuf.version>3.6.1</protobuf.version>
        <build.root.dir>${project.basedir}/..</build.root.dir>
        <build.output.dir>${build.root.dir}/build</build.output.dir>
        <protocPath>/usr/local/bin/protoc</protocPath>
    </properties>
```

I run this command `make mvn-build`
where I have CMakeLists.txt

```
add_custom_target(
  mvn-build
  COMMAND mvn -s
            -DPROTOC_PATH=$ENV{PROTOC}
            verify
)
```

`$ENV{PROTOC}` resolves to some mounted path, i.e. not `/usr/local/bin/protoc`.

I am getting this error. Why is it trying to use `protoc` in `/usr/local/bin/protoc`, and not the one in `$ENV{PROTOC}`?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.xolstice.maven.plugins:protobuf-maven-plugin:0.6.1:compile (default) on project ntnxdb-client-proto: An error occurred while invoking protoc: Error while executing process. Cannot run program "/usr/local/bin/protoc": error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
```

EDIT
I've changed to the below and still same error:

```
add_custom_target(
  mvn-opt ALL
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${NTNX_TOP_SOURCE_DIR}
  COMMAND mvn
            -DPROTOCPATH=$ENV{PROTOC}
            verify
)
```

Comment: "PROTOC_PATH" is different from "protocPath".

Comment: @JFMeier is it case sensitive as well?

Comment: I am not completely sure, but I would write it in the exact same way at both places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven properties are indeed case sensitive, so you'll have to use `-DprotocPath=...` in order to override the value.

There is a clear hint about this in the *Properties* section of the [Pom reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties) in the Maven doc:

> Note: While environment variables themselves are case-insensitive on
>   Windows, **lookup of properties is case-sensitive**.

(Bolding is mine).

You can also easily verify this by using e.g. the `verbose` setting for the maven-compiler-plugin:

```
mvn clean compile -Dmaven.compiler.verbose=true
```

vs.

```
mvn clean compile -Dmaven.compiler.VERBOSE=true
```

Only the former works.